# You’re not authorized to access this page. Please contact the administrator. After Integrating with SAML Active directory

Tags: active-directory, sonarqube, azure-active-directory

I tried to configure my SonarQube with active directory and once its done. It is showing this message. When i put the debug mode on , it is showing me these logs. Kindly share what i am missing.

**You’re not authorized to access this page. Please contact the administrator**

**Here are Logs:**

2019.12.10 14:33:21 ERROR web[AW7v2dtC1TkW09XXAAFy][o.a.a.a.AadIdentityProvider] Exception:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Group name cannot be empty

2019.12.10 14:33:21 DEBUG web[AW7v2dtC1TkW09XXAAFy][auth.event] **login failure [cause|Plugin did not call authenticate][method|OAUTH2][provider|EXTERNAL|Microsoft]**[IP|fe80:0:0:0:7d51:23e6:bd8f:3644%2|195.145.101.4][login|]

2019.12.10 14:33:21 DEBUG web[AW7v2dtC1TkW09XXAAF0][auth.event] login failure [cause|User must be authenticated][method|BASIC][provider|LOCAL|local][IP|fe80:0:0:0:7d51:23e6:bd8f:3644%2|195.145.101.4][login|]

**Details:**

Community Edition
Version 8.0 (build 29455)

Azure Active Directory (ADD)Sonar Qube plugin verison -  1.1

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the SonarQube Server URL set to HTTPs in the SonarQube settings.

Check also for the group name in both Azure AD and SonarQube.

Comment: How to change URL of sonarqube from http to Https? I am using this through Localhost:9000 and After enabling the proxy , It can be accessible outside. Kindly guide.

Answer (score 0):

We can use NGINX server to make https url

```
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/install/
```

and in /etc/nginx/site-enable/default file add

```
    server {

        listen 443 ssl;
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/sonar.access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/sonar.error.log;
        server_name sonarqube.yourdomain.com;
        ssl_certificate your combine certificate file;
        ssl_certificate_key your private key;
        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9000;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
        }
}
```

Please ensure that you have enabled "Allow users to sign-up" in Administration--> Azure Active Directory

hope this will resolve your error